# how to call data in block from custom table in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, collection

I am developing a reward points module.Two tables involve to this module(**e25m_rewardspoints**,**e25m_rewardpoints_history**).

I have created the My reward points page under customer my account page.

I want to show the relevant customers reward points in the page from table **e25m_rewardspoints**.
How to write this query in proper way?

```
"Select * from e25m_rewardspoints where customer_id="$customer_session_id""
```

Up to an echo from the page i have completed.
[image]

I don't want to use this way

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $connection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION'); 

        $result = $connection->fetchAll("Select * from e25m_rewardspoints where customer_id= ".$customerSession->getId());
        return $result;
    }else{
        return "user_not_login";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this, case, you need to create a **model,resource Mode, Collection model** class by which ***connected to***  the Database Table `e25m_rewardspoints`.

Some example:

https://www.pierrefay.com/magento2-training/create-magento2-model-database.html
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

**Create Model**

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Rewardspoints\Model;
use Magento\Cron\Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
class Rewardspoints extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    protected $_dateTime;

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Stackexchange\Rewardspoints\Model\ResourceModel\Rewardspoints::class);
    }
}
```

**Create ResourceModel**

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Rewardspoints\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Rewardspoints extends AbstractDb
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('e25m_rewardspoints', '[Table_Primary_key]');
    }
}
```

**Create Collection**

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Rewardspoints\Model\ResourceModel\Rewardspoints;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource collection
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Stackexchange\Rewardspoints\Model\Rewardspoints', 
            'Stackexchange\Rewardspoints\Model\ResourceModel\Rewardspoints');
    }
}
```

Now, At anywhere, at ***helper,block ,model classes***  you can get *particular customer reward point* by  factory collection class.

**Example suppose on Helper class:**

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Rewardspoints\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $rewardspointsFactory;
    protected $customerSession ;
    public function _construct(
        \Stackexchange\Rewardspoints\Model\RewardspointsFactory $rewardspointsFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession 
    ){
        $this->rewardspointsFactory = $rewardspointsFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function rewardPoints()
    {
         if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

            $Rewardspoints = $this->rewardspointsFactory->create();
            $collection = $Rewardspoints->getCollection();
            // customerId
            $customerId = $this->customerSession->getId();
            return $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
         }else{
             return false;
         }

    }
}
```